# Return value from externally called fs.Readfile() in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, return

I am trying to get a value returned from a function where I read and write a file using fs.readFile/writeFile in Node.

In my main server.js file, a request comes in and I then want to send an email from another file called sendEmail.js:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const sendMail = require('./sendEmail')

async function sendAnEmail() {
    let resultOfSend = await sendMail.sendEmail()
    resultOfSend.then((result)=>{
      // return the result
    }        
}

sendAnEmail();
```

In sendEmail I first read a file to get the email to send to,
then write to a second file
then, if all is good, I send an email (from a separate function):

```
async function sendEmail() {
    // Check if user exists
    fs.readFile('./file.json', (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            throw error
        }
        else {
            let users = JSON.parse(data)
            let dataToWrite = JSON.stringify(users)

            fs.writeFile('./file2.json', dataToWrite, (err) => {
                if(err) {
                    console.error(err)
                    throw error
                }
                else {
                    return generateEmail(users)
                        .then((info) => {
                           return info
                        })
                        .catch(console.log('err'))
                }
            })
        }
    })
}

async function generateEmail(user) {
        let msgText = 'hello world'

        // Set the mail options
        const mailOptions = {
           ...
        }
        
        // Send the mail
    let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
    return info
}

module.exports = {sendEmail}
```

What I can't get is a value for the resultOfSend variable. Keeps coming back undefined, I think because the promise hasn't yet been fulfilled.

How do I get a value to return from the sendEmail function back to the server.js file where it's called from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using await and async in `sendEmail` but not returning any `Promise` (So the `sendEmail` function doesn't return anything and this is why you get `undefined`).
Nevertheless, on the response you're trying to call `.then()` even though you used `await`.

So you should:

1. return Promise in the `sendEmail` function.
2. decide how you want to handle it, if you use async-await then dont use `.then()` and just analyze the variable and vice versa.
3. `generateEmail()` function should also return `Promise`.

For example:

```
async function sendEmail() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Check if user exists
    fs.readFile('./file.json', (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            reject()
        }
        else {
            let users = JSON.parse(data)
            let dataToWrite = JSON.stringify(users)

            fs.writeFile('./file2.json', dataToWrite, (err) => {
                if(err) {
                    console.error(err)
                    reject()
                }
                else {
                    generateEmail(users)
                        .then((info) => {
                            resolve(info)
                        })
                        .catch(
                            console.log('err')
                            reject()
                        )
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
}
```

Comment: For [my] reference, the initial call in the sendAnEmail() is written without the await as follows:

let resultOfSend = sendMail.sendEmail()

resultOf.then(data => {...}).catch(err=>{...})